# The POST method is not supported for this route()

Tags: php, laravel, post, resources, crud

I have this basic error but i cant fix it... can I have some help please ?

This is my view, and I tried with tokens @csrf and also @csrf-field and token.
I tried to write Post, post, POST.
(prat.store work well, the problem is update.)

```
@if(isset($ModificationMode))

<form method="post" action="{{route('prat.update', $DataPraticien ?? '')}}">
    @csrf
    @else
    <form action="{{route('prat.store')}}" method="post">
        @endif

//stuff
//stuff
/lalala


@if(isset($ModificationMode))
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Modifier Praticien</button>
    @else
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter Praticien</button>
    @endif
```

my controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $ModifPrat= Praticien::find($id);

      $ModifPrat->NOM = $request->input('NOM');
      $ModifPrat->ETAT_CIVIL = $request->input('ETAT_CIVIL');
      $ModifPrat->NOTE = $request->input('NOTE');
      $ModifPrat->NOTORIETE = $request->input('NOTORIETE');
      $ModifPrat->MENBRE_ASSOCIATION = $request->input('MEMBRE_ASSOCIATION');
      $ModifPrat->DIPLOME = $request->input('DIPLOME');
      $ModifPrat->save();
       return redirect()->route('homeAdmin', auth()->id());

    }
```

My route is a basic resource :

```
Route::resource('prat', 'PratController');
```

NB : The variable ModificationMode is a way to use the same Page for two distinct task. I used var_dump to debug it and the variable is set well and my prat.update is detected.

Thanks ;)

Comment: are you updating or inserting from the form?

Comment: this form is designed for insert and update (depending of my $ModificationMode) the insert work well, not the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're modifying, use this

`<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>`

you can refer to [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#form-method-spoofing) or [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: i dont have a patch function on my resource controller

Comment: You don't need to have a patch method in your `controller`. According to the documentation, to send `data` from a form to the update method, you will have to use `PUT` or `PATCH` form methods

Comment: thanks, i never used that before i really dont understand why i didnt needed it xD it worked for me with @method('PATCH')

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation for ResourceControllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers). There is a table that explains how Laravel maps the controller methods to the request types. Basically, you need to use the `@method` directive (or manually add the hidden input). So, your form should look like:

```
<form action="{{ route('prat.update') }}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    //...
</form>
```